# React Styling Bug

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, browser, styling

I hope you all are safe and you are doing well this evening.

I have been spinning my wheels on this problem for the last few days. Basically, when my component is rendered, it receives a list of json results as props, and when it receives those props, it maps over the array to create a nested JSX element for each item as such :

```
For every item in json result array, map
div styled with display:flex //root
   div flex 1 //children
   div flex 2 //children
div
```

```
import React from "react";
import { phi as goldenRatio, e, pow } from "mathjs";

const defaultStyle = {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    flex: goldenRatio,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column"
};

/* When trying to add an item to a list that is no problem
The problem occurs when trying to add a nested item that declares the display flex property

Perhaps generate side for Name, then generate side for Description separately (components)? Just some thoughts..

where we would have the layout already set up for the two sides
*/
const DisplayCoronaItems = props => {
    const { coronaListResults } = props;

    console.log(coronaListResults);
    return coronaListResults.map((item, index) => {
        return <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>Wow an item</div>;
    });
};

const CoronaBody = props => {
    //merge main style
    const { style } = props;
    const {
        coronaList: { results: coronaListResults = [] }
    } = props;
    const mergedStyle = { ...defaultStyle, ...style };

    return (
        <section style={mergedStyle}>
            <DisplayCoronaItems coronaListResults={coronaListResults} />
        </section>
    );
};

export default CoronaBody;
```

Try it yourself, you will notice on safari that you would get similar results. Safari will scale your text height and width down proportional to the flexbox dimensions. And the behavior is divergent from how chrome behaves, which in my opinion behaves normally.

Comment: Can you provide a running codesandbox (or similar) that reproduces the issue? It's not really anyone else's responsibility to get your code up and functional just to debug it. Is the issue in `DisplayCoronaItems` where you map some elements? You map to a single div with display: flex, but then say the issue is when you do something different. Please post the "something different" code that is causing the issue.

Comment: Hey Drew, I resolved the issue. The issue was due to a anti-pattern in my css which was caused by setting the initial width and height to 100 vw and 100 vh instead of 100% and 100%.